# What type of threshold weather-stripping goes here?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

[image: Door Jamb]

This is for an external door to the garage. It originally had some rubber weatherstrip in it, but it was all busted up and falling apart and dry so that it squeaked really badly. I stupidly didn't take any pictures when I took it out, and now I can't figure out exactly what type goes back in here.

I haven't tried unscrewing the screws to see if that helps me or not since I don't want to break it if I don't need to touch it.

What is this type called so that I can search for it? And do you have a picture of what it should look like, ideally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that it had a conventional rubber or vinyl gasket inserted into the slots on either side of the screws:

[image]
<sub>[image source](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2007/01/01/replacing-a-door-threshold)</sub>

With some diligence you may find a new part to fit, but it'll need to be just the right height. It may be easier to replace the entire threshold with a new kit.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look around the jamb to see if I can find a manufacturer or model or anything that might give me a clue. Failing that, I suppose I'll measure the distance between the slots and wander around a hardware store with a tape measure and see if I can get something close. The right side looks almost exactly like what I would expect it to look like before it was all torn up. Replacing the whole threshold and matching the stain and getting it exactly right under the existing jamb looks awful, I'd rather freeze, lol.